# How to get the last updated price from a pivot table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation

Here are the table schema

customers

```
------------------------------
id  name
------------------------------
1   joe
4   jane
```

products

```
------------------------------
id  title 
------------------------------
1   iphone  
2   ipad
```

customers_products

```
------------------------------
id  product_id  customer_id
------------------------------
1   1       1   
2   2       1
3   1       5
4   1       9
```

prices

```
-------------------------------------------
id  product_id  price   created_at 
-------------------------------------------
3   1       300         2017-04-01
4   2       450         2017-04-01
5   2       500         2017-04-02
6   1       320         2017-04-04
7   1       200         2017-04-05
```

What I'm trying to get is this result of last price of each products categorised by user id, like this

```
user_id product_id       last_price
1       1                200
```

Which is last updated price of product no 1 (price_history row no 7)

this is what I've done so far and it has given incorrect results

```
select 
id,prices.price as current_price,customers_products as price
from prices
join products on products.id = prices.product_id
join customers_products on customers_products.product_id = prices.product_id
where customers_products.customer_id = 1
group by prices.product_id order by prices.id desc
```

Would really appreciate your help guys!.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of your query, and what exactly is wrong with the output?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tuple in where in for get the max price join to your customers_products

```
select  customers_products.customer_id , customers_products.product_id, prices.price as last_price
from customers_products
inner join prices on prices.product_id = customers_products
where ( created_at ,product_id) in (
    select max(created_at ), product_id  
    from price 
    group product_id
)
```